# How to click link with changing attributes using imacros?

Tags: google-chrome, macros, click, href, imacros

I am creating a macro in which I want to click the anchor element.
The problem with this anchor element is that all the attributes changes randomly after every click.

Below is the anchor link

```
<a id="bLMa" class="**btn valign-wrapper** pulse **animated** lime accent-2 black-text">**Stаrt**</a>
```

Items marked between star always remain same. All other items changes continuously.

The location of the anchor changes randomly after every click.

I tried below steps

```
TAG XPATH="//*[@class="animated"]"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=Class:animated
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Start
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*Start*
```

I always get the same error as **Element Not Found.**

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try combining Attributes to identify the anchor you want to find as per http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG_parameters_explained#Multiple_ATTR_parameters

For your specific example something like

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=class:*animated*&&TXT:*Start*
```

could work, looking for the class `animated` AND the text `Start` together in an anchor.

Comment: Still not working. Same Error
RuntimeError: element A specified by class:*animated*&&TXT:*Start* was not found, line: 3

You can check the same by joining this link https://adbtc.top/r/l/303975

You can check the functioning of start button here

Comment: Can you try if that works for you in iMacros for Firefox? I am not certain about the differences between the Chrome and the Firefox version...